# Redirection of URL's without a .html Suffix

Tags: regex, .htaccess, magento, redirect

I have an old website that has URL's like:

```
/my-category/my-product
```

and in my new website, I've managed to keep the 'category' part the same in a lot of case (but not all), but I want to redirect their old products that don't have the .html suffix to the category.

So  `/my-category/my-product` will get redirected to `/my-category/` but `/my-category/my-product.html` will be ignored as it has `.html` on the end. The new website products have `.html` on the end, where the old website doesn't.

I also need to stop further rules processing.

Comment: You need a regex and a htaccess pro to answer this. Also, your last paragraph is a bit confusing...Could you clarify? First paragraph says old site has /my-category/ did they have /my_category also? (Lol)

Comment: Removed last paragraph as had a different way to do it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expresion will match any number of `\` followed by a string **not** containing a dot. Then will not match the url will html extension.

```
^(/[\w-]+)+$
```

[View regex state diagram](https://www.debuggex.com/r/H32Nm5MTZU6EKIrb)